# Java Shutdown hooks on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, java, sddm

I am using the following systemd service to shutdown a `Java` program gracefully when shutting down a PC running Lubuntu 20.04.1. The script in `/usr/local/bin/pre-shutdown` searches for all running `Java` programs and terminates them.

```
[Unit]
Description=Kills some programs that prevent proper (fast) shutdown
Requires=sddm.service
After=sddm.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/pre-shutdown

[Install]
WantedBy=sddm.service
```

When stopping the `sddm` service using `systemctl stop sddm` the script finds the program and kills it (all registered shutdown hooks are run). But if I shutdown the PC using `shutdown now` or `reboot` some other process seems to kill the Java program before the script is run (with no shutdown hooks being run) as it does not find any runninng `Java` programs.

What do I have to change in the service definition to have the script run before my `Java` program is killed even when the system is shutdown (and not only sddm is stopped).

On Lubuntu 14.04 we had the same problem and were able to solve it by stopping the program using a `pre-stop` script in `etc/init/lightdm.conf`, but that is unfortunatelly only supported by `upstart`.